# Task Alerts Issues

Tags: wss-3.0, alert

I have suddenly facing an issue relating to Task Notification by email.
All was working perfectly but now people from my site do not get an alert email when a task is assigned to them.

By Alert email I mean the default email which Sharepoint sends. It is not a workflow made by us but its a default feature.

I use WSS 3.0!

Can someone please help me out as many people from my company are dependant on email alerts only & its frustrating when a task goes unattended.

If you need more information from my side please let me know.

Thx!

-saumil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this troubleshooting guide

http://sharepointalert.info/troubleshooting-sharepoint-alerts/

[image: SharePoint Alert troubleshooting flowchart]
<sub>(source: [sharepointalert.info](http://sharepointalert.info/wp-content/uploads/2009/11/flowchart.gif))</sub>

Comment: good flow chat :)

Answer (score 2):

Check the timer jobs for Email Alerts in Central Admin, something might've stalled or fallen over.

Comment: Also, in the task lists settings (I think in Advanced Settings) there is a "Send e-mail when ownership is assigned" checkbox.  Be sure it is still checked.

Comment: I have tried both things given above but still no luck! Any other place to look into?